# Extract data points from text

Tags: python

I'd like to extract data from a sentence. I know that this is not a simple and easy process but was wondering what would be the best way about doing so. For example I'd have the sentence:

```
The silver boat moved through the dark waters, light by the moonlight.
```

From that I'd like to get:

```
Boat: sliver, moving through water //moving through water referring to Water:
Water: dark, light by the moonlight, boat moving //boat moving referring to Boat:
Moonlight: lighting water
```

Basically I'd like to get all the words that describe the noun whether a single word or short phrase. Some details are kept both twice (the item `Boat` has a reference to `water` and the item `Water` reference to `boat`)

I was thinking about getting a list of nouns and finding all them in the sentence. Then I'd somehow get everything describing it (all the links).

If someone has already done something similar or if there's a way to get all related data from a sentence, please tell me or give a link.

Comment: Have you looked at [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/)?  I think they have the tools to at least get you started if not modules that will do what you want exactly.

Comment: @jtweeder No, thanks, I'll definitely do that.